# Name for the logical operator A & (~B)

Tags: logical-operators, nomenclature, truthtable

Is there a name for logical AND with the negation (`~`) of the second variable, i.e:

```
A & (~B)
```

The truth table for such operation is:

```
0 & (~0) = 0
0 & (~1) = 0
1 & (~0) = 1
1 & (~1) = 0
```

And in longer sequences of bits,

```
A       = 10110011
B       = 10111001
A & B   = 10110001
A &(~B) = 00000010
```

PS - I'm interested with OR with the negation of the second variable, too.

Comment: The OR with negation is called implication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Incredible. A & (~B) is called [Material nonimplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_nonimplication), and A | (~B) is called [Material implication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication) Seems that [every possible binary operation has a name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Binary_operations).

Comment: I was going to write that as an answer.

Comment: Except I would back it from [Wikipedia: logical connective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Common_logical_connectives)

Comment: Which one is better: "Logical NAND" or "Alternative denial"?

Comment: @JanDvorak Hilarious. Joint me for a denial?

Answer (score 3):

The set theoretic term is the "relative complement" of B with respect to A.

Answer (score 1):

I like to call it bit clearer. You find it in code also in the
form by using an assignment:

A = A & ~B

Or more compact as:

A &= ~B

Example: Before: A = 0x0007, B=0x0004
   After: A = 0x0003

It has the effect that it clears the bits B from A. But relative 
complement, and hence the name difference, you could write 
it as follows A \ B, like the set difference, is also a good name.